# Backing up contacts on SDcard

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Is to possible to copy the contacts2.db SQLite file in a non-rooted phone to SD Card programatically. If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps don't have access to other apps' databases, so the answer is no, you can't.

There is an API to read all the contacts ([ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html)) that you can use to store the contact information in your own database and/or file in the external storage.

Comment: So if I want to backup my contacts2.db to SD Card, what's the best way to do it? Use ContactsContract to read each contact individually and then store it in a custom DB created in the SD Card?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable solution.